# Firebase signInWithRedirect using GoogleAuthProvider not working on phone

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to enable google sign up using the Firebase signInWithRedirect using GoogleAuthProvider on my web app but I'm having issues getting it to work on phones.The way I have it set up works perfectly on desktops. I am having issues getting the sign up with google auth provider to work on mobile phones (both ios and android).

What's currently happening is I would click sign up with google button on my web app, the google login page would load and I would sign into my google account, then it would redirect me back to the sign up page on my web app. My google user info is never updated to firebase authentication. It seems like the authentication never happens. Any idea why this might happen? I will include relevant code below.

**AuthContext.js**

```
    function googleSignin() {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        return signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
    }
```

**Signup.js**
handling the redirect.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getRedirectResult(auth).then(
            result => {
                if (result !== null) {
                    navigate("/")
                }
            },
            err => {
                setError(err)
            })
    }, [])
```

the google signin button

```
<GoogleButton className="mx-auto mt-3" onClick={googleSignin} />
```